# Trying to figure out recursive version for this code

Tags: java, recursion

I have this code which works fine.

```
String thirdChild = getChild(columnsLength, paramsMap, index + 1);
        String fourthChild = getChild(columnsLength, paramsMap, index + 2);

        if (thirdChild != null) {
                    for(Map<String, Object> child : children) {
                        List<Map<String, Object>> children2 = getChildGroupObjects((List<Map<String, String>>)child.get("items"), aggregatableColumns, thirdChild);
                        if(fourthChild != null) {
                            for(Map<String, Object> child2 : children2) {
                                List<Map<String, Object>> children3 = getChildGroupObjects((List<Map<String, String>>)child2.get("items"), aggregatableColumns, fourthChild);
                                log.info("fourth");
                                child2.put("items", children3);
                                child2.put("subGroups", children3);
                                child2.put("hasSubgroups", true);
                            }
                        }
                        log.info("third");
                        child.put("items", children2);
                        child.put("subGroups", children2);
                        child.put("hasSubgroups", true);
                    }

                }
```

I have tried to make a recursive version of this code here

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> recursiveGrouping(List<Map<String, Object>> children, List<String> aggregatableColumns,
                                                        String childObject, int columnsLength, Map<String, String[]> paramsMap, int index) {
        String childObj = getChild(columnsLength, paramsMap, index);
        index++;
        if(childObj == null) {
            return new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        }

        for(Map<String, Object> child : children) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> children2 = getChildGroupObjects((List<Map<String, String>>)child.get("items"), aggregatableColumns, childObj);

            child.put("items", children2);
            child.put("subGroups", children2);
            child.put("hasSubgroups", true);
            List<Map<String, Object>> childList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
            childList.add(child);



            recursiveGrouping(childList, aggregatableColumns, childObj, columnsLength, paramsMap, index);


        }

        return children;
    }
```

but it is not working on the browser. May I kindly ask for some help please. If there is a problem with my question please inform me about it and I will correct immediately.

The code is supposed to group hashmaps with similar key but that is the scope of another function call. Basically in this code, we just call the method and for each iteration of the loop go in one step deep (if exists) and figure out the grouping candidates (list of hasmaps)

Shown is just 2 levels, I am making recursion method to have it go to nth level.

The get child call will group the childs with the same key of HashMap. Basically they are similar structure but normally less size of list.

Comment: A little explanation about what the code is supposed to do ?

Comment: I have updated the original post. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this piece of code is giving me the proper results

```
    private List<Map<String, Object>> recursiveGrouping(List<Map<String, Object>> children, List<String> aggregatableColumns,
                                                        String childObject, int columnsLength, Map<String, String[]> paramsMap, int index) {
        String childObj = getChild(columnsLength, paramsMap, index);
        List<Map<String, Object>> childrenToReturn = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        index++;
        if(childObj == null) {
            return new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        }

        for(Map<String, Object> child : children) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> children2 = getChildGroupObjects((List<Map<String, String>>)child.get("items"), aggregatableColumns, childObj);
            recursiveGrouping(children2, aggregatableColumns, childObj, columnsLength, paramsMap, index);
            child.put("items", children2);
            child.put("subGroups", children2);
            if(children2.size() > 0) {
                child.put("hasSubgroups", true);
            }
            childrenToReturn.addAll(children2);
        }

        return childrenToReturn;
    }
```